Was Mary married at the time of the Annunciation?
Was Mary married at the time of the Annunciation, or only "engaged" / betrothed?

As with a comment to a previous one-line question, and after looking at your posted question list, I wonder if we should be closing these for being "mindless social fun" (see [help/dont-ask]). As before, why is this question important? What research have you performed? Etc. Not closable, but worthy of a down vote.

She was a wife at the time of the Annunciation; Mt. 1:20: "fear not to take unto thee Mary thy wife".
The Jews had two ceremonies:

Espousal, which is more than a mere engagement or future promise to marry; "the Hebrew espousal was equivalent to our valid but not consummated marriage." (Llamera, O.P. p. 22).
Nuptials, solemnization of the marriage, "the solemn entry of the bride into her husband's home amidst great festivities and rejoicing" (ibid. p. 19)

The Annunciation occurred between her espousal and nuptials.

The Jews had two ceremonies - why is the past tense used here, as if Jews stopped existing?

@AviAvraham By "Jews" I mean those before the destruction of the Temple in 70 AD and the end of their priesthood.

The distinction between kiddushin and nissuin still exists today

@AviAvraham Interesting. I'm not familiar with those terms. Do they mean what how I define espousal vs. nuptials?

Yep, they correspond to those terms

@AviAvraham Wiktionary must be wrong; it says kiddushin = "engagement (promise to marry)". Maybe by "marry" it means consummate the (already contracted) marriage?

@AviAvraham - Matthew 1:18 says that "Mary was pledged to be married to Joseph, but before they came together she was found to be with child through the Holy Spirit." No consummation of the marriage contract had taken place.

@Lesley Does nuptials / nissuin necessarily imply consummation? I thought it was simply the bride entering the husband's house.

@Geremia's answer is correct as far as it goes. However, we should be aware that there is no biblical record that an actual wedding between Mary and Joseph ever happened. Indeed, the Gospel of Luke states clearly that they were still in a state of betrothal on the day they arrived in Bethlehem and Jesus was born.

Joseph too went up from Galilee... (to Bethlehem), 5 to be enrolled with Mary, his betrothed,
who was with child. 6 While they were there, the time came for her to
have her child, 7 and she gave birth to her firstborn son. She
wrapped him in swaddling clothes and laid him in a manger, because
there was no room for them in the inn.

Thus, although it is quite true that a betrothal was legally binding, it is also true that there had been no wedding ceremony at the time of the Annunciation - and this applies both to the Annunciation to Mary (in Luke) and the Annunciation to Joseph (in Matthew). They remained in a state of betrothal when Jesus was born, according to Luke. However, this fact does not mean that they were "living in sin" for this concept did not apply in ancient times.
